# New to nginx: How to properly serve static files (especially images)?

Tags: nginx

I am new to making use of nginx, so please bare with me for asking this question.

Serving images onto my website has been the only issue I have been unable to figure out. I have tried to find tutorials from forums and videos, but aside from them being several years old, their methods have not worked for me. I have even read the guides on nginx's website, but they too are not providing enough information on how it is done.

It might have to do with me using Linux Ubuntu and using Vultr as my VPS, but I am not so sure if using a different OS and VPS would be the cause of this problem. Please help me out here.

```
server {
        server_name lockheartdynamite.xyz ;
        root /var/www/lockheart ;
        index index.html ;
        location /image {
                autoindex on ;
                alias /home/metallic_halls/image ;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404 ;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lockheartdynamite.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/lockheartdynamite.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = lockheartdynamite.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
        server_name lockheartdynamite.xyz ;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

This code results in me getting a 404 page and opening up the error log mentions "no such file, or directory".  While I understand how the location block functions, I am mainly confused on if serving has anything to do with actual files on my computer, or if they actually need to be created through nginx to be identified.

For example, in the beginner's guide on nginx's website, there is a line which highlights:

["First, create the /data/www directory and put an index.html file with any text content into it and create the /data/images directory and place some images in it."](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#static)

I want to know if the directory's have to be created in the terminal/desktop, or through nginx? If it is through nginx, how do I place the images inside the directory?